how to use axios (post) in content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded in react typescript?
import { Fragment, useState, FormEvent } from "react";
import { Listbox, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { CheckIcon, ChevronUpDownIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { Label } from "./label";
import { Input } from "./input";
import { cn } from "../../utils/cn";
import axios from "axios";
interface Option {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
const CascadingDropdowns: React.FC = () => {
  const [textInputValue, setTextInputValue] = useState("");
  const [selectedYearmonth, setSelectedYearmonth] = useState<string>("");
  const [selectedOption1, setSelectedOption1] = useState<string>("");
  const [selectedOption2, setSelectedOption2] = useState<string>("");
  const [selectedOption3, setSelectedOption3] = useState<string>("");
  const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState<any>(null); 

  const yearmonth: Option[] = [
    { id: 2, name: "Tahun" },
    { id: 3, name: "Bulan" },
  ]; 
  const options1: Option[] = [
    { id: 1, name: "Laki-laki" },
    { id: 2, name: "Perempuan" },
  ];
 
  const options2: { [key: string]: Option[] } = {
    "Laki-laki": [{ id: 1, name: "Suboption 1" }],
    Perempuan: [
      { id: 2, name: "Hamil" },
      { id: 3, name: "Menyusui" },
      { id: 4, name: "Tidak Keduanya" },
    ],
  };
 
  const options3: { [key: string]: Option[] } = {
    Hamil: [
      { id: 1, name: "Trimester I" },
      { id: 2, name: "Trimester II" },
      { id: 3, name: "Trimester III" },
    ],
    Menyusui: [
      { id: 4, name: "Semester Pertama" },
      { id: 5, name: "Semester Kedua" },
    ],
  };

  
  const handleTextInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setTextInputValue(e.target.value);
  };
  
  const handleYearmonthChange = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedYearmonth(value);
  };
  
  const handleDropdown1Change = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedOption1(value);
    setSelectedOption2("");
    setSelectedOption3(""); 
  };

  const handleDropdown2Change = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedOption2(value);
    setSelectedOption3(""); 
  };

  const handleDropdown3Change = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedOption3(value);
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const formData = new URLSearchParams();
      formData.append("inputText", textInputValue);
      formData.append("selectedYearmonth", selectedYearmonth);
      formData.append("selectedOption1", selectedOption1);
      formData.append("selectedOption2", selectedOption2);
      formData.append("selectedOption3", selectedOption3);

      const response = await fetch(
        "https://group4-prplh.000webhostapp.com/public/home/find",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
          body: formData.toString(),
        }
      );

      const data = await response.json();

      if (response.ok && data.status === "success") {
        setResponseData(data);
      } else {
        console.error("Error:", data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  function classNames(...classes: string[]) {
    return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div >
        <h2 >
          Welcome to Takaran Gizi
        </h2>
        <p >
          Login to Takaran Gizi if you can because we don&apos;t have a login
          flow yet
        </p>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="">
            ....
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            id="submitButton"
            hidden={
              !selectedOption1 ||
              (selectedOption1 === "Perempuan" &&
                !selectedOption2 &&
                !selectedOption3) ||
              (selectedOption1 === "Perempuan" &&
                selectedOption2 === "Hamil" &&
                !selectedOption3) ||
              (selectedOption1 === "Perempuan" &&
                selectedOption2 === "Menyusui" &&
                !selectedOption3)
            }
          >
            Submit &rarr;
            <BottomGradient />
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="w-[1px] h-[70%] rounded-md mx-3 bg-black"></div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


export { CascadingDropdowns };

this is my code.
i want to get data depends form input user that include age(textInputValue), gender(selectedOption1), condition(selectedOption2), additional condition(selectedOption3) and post form using axios with my API (https://group4-prplh.000webhostapp.com/public/home/find) with content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. the formData is textInputValue, selectedOption1, selectedOption2, selectedOption3. but, axios always still error.
i want to make form that will get data from database as return. i tried using axios but always error, anyone help me?
